# How can I get multiple entities values from a table in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
String strhql="select max(e.salary),min(e.salary),avg(e.salary) from Employee e";
Query q=s.createQuery(strhql);
List l=q.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is returning a list of objects

Effectively

```
List l = q.list()
```

could be 'typed' to

```
List<Object[]> l = (List<Object[]>) q.list();
```

then you can do

```
 maxSal = (Integer)l.get(0)[0]
```

etc etc

Your question could be clearer but I think this is the answer to what you are asking. If not then please add more details to the question